# Numerical evidence of Beilinson's conjecture in local fields and function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, nt.number-theory

The famous Beilinson's conjecture predicts a relationship between the regulator map in $K$-theory and special value of $L$-function generalizing the Dirichlet's theorem in number theory. Please see this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2703/beilinson-conjectures) for details.

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405040) by Tim Dokchitser, Rob de Jeu, Don Zagier, the authors construct families of hyperelliptic curves over $\mathbf{Q}$ of arbitrary genus g with (at least) g integral elements in $K_2$. With these elements they compute the regulator numerical and compare the regulator with special value of $L$-function of these curves which give numerical evidence of Beilinson's conjecture for $K_2$ of curves.

Here are my questions:

Is there explicitly formulated conjectures in p-adic fields and function fields as in number fields? Does one can do similar computations for curves over these fields? If not, what are the main obstacles?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in Colmez' Bourbaki survey "Fonctions L p-adiques", available here:

http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~colmez/bric-a-brac.html

Section 2.8 is called "p-adic Beilinson conjectures".

See also his other survey (on the same page) called "La conjecture de Birch et Swinnerton-Dyer p-adique".