# Beilinson's conjecture on the level of spectra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I refer to the MO post here for a statement of Beilinson's conjectures about the Beilinson's regulator as a map from motivic cohomology: [Beilinson conjectures](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2703/beilinson-conjectures)

A result of Bunke-Nikolaus-Tamme shows that the regulator can be [refined to a map of spectra](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.05667). Has there been any formulation or even spectulation as to how the statement regarding the $L$-value in this setting?